# Input tipo range no muestra rango

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3

Estoy creando un formulario cuyo contenido consiste en tener algunos input de tipo range. Sin embargo, no se muestran los rangos correspondientes y además de eso, quisiera saber cómo puedo contar con dos sliders en vez de uno, parecido a éste por ejemplo:

[image: input range]

Este es parte del código que tengo del formulario (y que representa un input range):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Rango Impuesto Verde:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input id="iv" type="range" name="i_verde" min="0" max="1000000000" class="form-control"/>
        </div>
</div>
```

Estoy utilizando Bootstrap junto con el tema Material Design for Bootstrap

Saludos y gracias de antemano

Answer (score 3):

Quizas algo como esto

[Slider for Bootstrap](http://seiyria.com/bootstrap-slider/)

en el `Example 2` se implementa el slider tal cual lo necesitas

```js
$("#ex2").slider({});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/6.0.16/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/6.0.16/css/bootstrap-slider.css">


 <b>10</b> <input id="ex2" type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="10" data-slider-max="1000" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="[250,450]"/> <b> 1000</b>
```

---

Otra alternativa podria ser

[noUiSlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/)

si analiza los ejemplos, veras que se implementan lo que necesitas

Solo es cuestion de ver cual se adapta mejor a tu diseño

Comment: Aunque tu respuesta ayuda, seria mejor que coloques el código acá.

Comment: @WilfredoP pero que codigo voy a poner si solo estoy recomendando librerias que puede usar para implementar el slide (con las caracteristicas que describe), el codigo saldra de la evaluacion de los diferentes ejemplos y ver cual se adapta al diseño del sitio, no hay un unico ejemplo en codigo

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro pero se tratan de librerias de terceros (que implementan el slider), aunque ponga ejemplos de como usarlas esto queda atado a que las librerias esten vigentes. O se debe poner el codigo de toda la libreria completa ? Ademas no se cual va a utilizar, ya que propongo dos que se aproximan a la apariencia del control que busca

Comment: Ahora ya esta mucho mejor ;)